# How to ask "Do you have...." when asking if a store carries a particular item?

Tags: questions

I have a feeling "Tu as [quelque chose] ?" is not quite right; I am inclined to guess "On a [quelque chose] ?" is on the right track but I am of course by no means sure.

For example *Do you have balsamic vinegar here?*

Comment: "Vendez-vous [quelque chose] dans votre magasin?" I wonder if this one sounds idiomatic enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be the simplest way to put it:

- Est-ce que vous *avez* du vinaigre balsamique ici?

You could also use:

- Avez-vous du vinaigre balsamique ici?

As per the comments below, you should't have the 'ici' at the end of the sentence.

Comment: I wouldn't use the final "ici" in both your sentences.

Comment: I agree @GéraudBenazet, but I chose to use the same form as the one used in English.  I wouldn't not have used 'here' in the english sentence either.

Comment: Then just don't use "*ici*" in your answer for it to be idiomatic and state you wouldn't have used "here" either in English.